# how can i make a assign mongoose result in local variable in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

[I want to add my sum of monthlyorder in local variable and print outside find function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUYs8.png)

Comment: Please post code and not Images of code ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a
question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)